# Codeforces 427E: impossible to write fast enough solution in Java

Tags: java

I'm convinced that there are many people here which are interested with Codeforce problems, so here the issue:

**Problem:** I stuck with solving [one of Codeforces problems](http://randomconstant.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/codeforces-427e-police-patrol/). I get `Time limit exceeded` at 21th test. I've found [solition](http://randomconstant.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/codeforces-427e-police-patrol/) but it seems even slower than mine.

After considering a while I decided that it's impossible to write a faster solution in Java 7.

**Question:** Is it possible to write a faster solution in Java 7?

**My Solution:**

```
public class PolicePatrol {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        int criminalAmount = in.nextInt();
        int patrolCarCapacity = in.nextInt();
        int[] criminalLocations = new int[criminalAmount];
        for (int i = 0; i < criminalLocations.length; i++)
            criminalLocations[i] = in.nextInt();

        long distance = calcDistance(criminalLocations, patrolCarCapacity);
        out.print(distance);
        out.flush();
    }

    protected static long calcDistance(int[] criminals, int patrolCapacity) {
        // put patrol on the position of the middle criminal
        int patrolPosition = criminals[criminals.length / 2]; 

        double itr = (criminals.length - 1) / 2.0;
        // number of travels to the left from the police station
        int itrLeft = (int) Math.ceil(Math.ceil(itr) / ((double) patrolCapacity)); 
        //number of travels to the right from the police station
        int itrRight = (int) Math.ceil(Math.floor(itr) / ((double) patrolCapacity)); 

        long distance = 0;

        int lo = 0;
        while (itrLeft-- > 0) {
            distance += patrolPosition - criminals[lo];
            lo = lo + patrolCapacity;
        }

        int hi = criminals.length - 1;
        while (itrRight-- > 0) {
            distance += criminals[hi] - patrolPosition;
            hi -= patrolCapacity;
        }
        return 2 * distance;
    }
}
```

**Update:** If you aren't interested in solving Codeforce problems, lets define the simplest task.

```
Input:
arraySize
step
array

Output:
Number that represents summary of all Math.abs(array[array.length / 2] - array[i]) for all `i % step == 0`
```

Comment: "I decided that it's impossible to write a faster solution in Java 7." vs. "Is it possible to write a faster solution in Java 7?" - let the fight begin!

Comment: Please don't require people to have to reach out to external websites in order to answer your question.  Encapsulate any necessary specifications directly.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth look at update section of my question please

Comment: What's the time complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: Maybe your computer is too slow!

Comment: @Eric It is tested on a remote judge

Comment: @NiklasB. calculating `Math.abs(array[array.length / 2] - array[i])` N/step times. At my local PC it performs about 70 milliseconds for one hundred millions input

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the code other than that you're wondering if there's a better way to do it? If not, it's off-topic. Stack Overflow is [a question-and-answer resource, not a discussion forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92115/228805). It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers. Try [codereview.se].

Comment: @AdiInbar It's too slow?

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm not sure I understand your comment as a response to mine. My point was that if the problem is "it's too slow" and the question is "how can I write this more efficiently?", then it's off-topic for Stack Overflow and belongs at [codereview.se].

Comment: @Adi I can find nothing against optimization questions in the help center, care to give a reference?   Note that it might be on-topic on *both* sites

Comment: @NiklasB. The "on-topic" help page is pretty generic and doesn't get into the differences between the SE programming sites, but here's a [meta post by a mod that sums it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211790/228805). In fact, Code Review and Programmers were [established for the *purpose* of directing questions that are subjective or discussion-oriented away from SO and narrow SO's focus to specific coding issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102869/228805). See also the paragraph beginning with "As for the fragmentation" in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/228805).

Comment: Note that there may be some cases of overlap, and if a question gets into speed or efficiency issues of specific aspects of the code, I'd agree that it's appropriate for SO, but a question that posts some code and broadly asks "how can I make it better/faster/more efficient?" is about as clear-cut a case as possible for Code Review rather than SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127320/228805.

Comment: @adi you should actually read that thread and the responses in the comments to the answer: This is not a "you could try x, y, z" type of question. There's a specific, single point of failure here which just needs to be pointed out. The code is self-contained and runnable and can even be submitted to codeforces as is for experiments. Maybe if OP had already managed to get AC but wanted to improve the working code in some way, I would agree, but in the current form this is at least on-topic on both sites, if not even off-topic on CR. But it's closed anyway for other reasons, so no point arguing

Comment: And in reference to the meta post, it does *not* "work as intended" in the current form. In any case, even if we determine that it might be more on-topic in CR, that's not a reason to close it in SO, unless it's explicitly and without a doubt off-topic here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Scanner` is notoriously slow](http://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/~jim/java-io.html). I got [accepted with your code](http://codeforces.com/contest/427/submission/6557407) after just replacing it with a faster implementation. The code is taken from the [IFMO training Java template](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/trains/information/Template.java):

```
static class FastScanner {
    BufferedReader br;
    StringTokenizer st;

    FastScanner(InputStream f) {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
    }

    String next() throws IOException {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        }
        return st.nextToken();
    }

    int nextInt() throws IOException {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }
}
```

For 1M integers in the input, this cut down the time needed for input parsing from ~1.3s down to ~0.35s on my machine, which is an improvement of a factor of 4.